# How to implement Push notification in Windows phone 7 and Sqlite?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, windows-phone-7

I have an App targeted for `WP7` and the `push notification` which triggers `sqlite` code to insert messages into `sqlite DB`. This works fine when the App is in the foreground, but not work when App is the background.

What is the best approach to take so that when user received `push notification`, it can execute `sqlite` code in the background?

I read up on `background agent`, but wasn't sure how `background agent` can receive data from `push notification`.

Any example or idea will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. As a work around, I will store all messages on the server. When user first start the app, it will automatically download messages from cloud to sqlite. Then, only pusbh notification received will trigger data refresh from cloud.